# Data structure for spatial data

Tags: data-structures, ocaml, functional-programming

I am looking for a good functional data structure to store spatial (point) data. The data structure should allow simple epsilon queries for points already present. Also I need to modify the data quite often. This means points can move and should be able to be updated in the data structure. This can probably be handled using a normal delete/add, but a real move might be faster.

For now I am thinking about using [quad/oct-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (or higher), since the move part should be quite easy to do. However quad-trees are known to be worse as far as balancing is concerned. [KD-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) might be another choice, but the update seems quite nasty. Also most spacial data structure implementations I can find are only procedural and I am using a functional language.

Comment: Just to clarify: is an epsilon query a query to find points which are within a specified distance of an given point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KD-trees or Quad/Oct trees are reasonable choices.

Examples in Haskell:

- [QuadTree](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/spacepart/0.1.0.0/doc/html/Data-SpacePart-QuadTree.html)
- [KD Tree](https://github.com/mjsottile/publicstuff/blob/master/dla3d/optimized-haskell7/DLA/KDTree.hs)

Both are pretty simple to encode as purely functional data structures.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you are using it and quickly the points move, you might also consider [sweep and prune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_and_prune). Basically, you keep the points sorted in one dimension (say x). If points change places very seldom, running insertion sort for every simulation step will actually be very quick.

(I think your two suggestions are already quite good, by the way)

Answer (score 4):

[This old paper](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1980/1980-02.pdf) by Overmars and van Leeuwen describes the *pseudo quadtree* - a quadtree which can also balance itself as insertions and deletions progress. The amortized cost of insertions and deletions is something like `O(log^d(n))` and can even be traded against the amount of balancing done (you can read more about this in the paper).

Answer (score 3):

[R-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and R*-Trees are also another solution, easy to implement.

See https://github.com/mariusaeriksen/ocaml-rtree (in OCaml) for an example.

I used them in an evacuation simulation, the update step is not so slow as that.

Comment: Seems quite good, although I had to fix some things in order to get it to work here. Thanks for the help...